# Не работает console log

Tags: javascript, firefox

В firefox после сегодняшнего обновления у меня перестал работать `console.log();` что делать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Всё там работает..... возможно вы что-то не так делаете....что-нибудь не так с экранированием в коде к примеру и т.д...... ошибку выдает? нет? что получается? что делаете?

Comment: да там даже console.log('123'); не работает , может это только у меня... ошибки вы выдаёт пишет тк "undefined"

Comment: добавьте скриншот того как "не работает"

Comment: все я добавил  тк толку

Comment: Судя по скриншоту отключен журнал.
Нужно нажать CTRL+SHIFT+K. Откроется консоль. В нижнем ряду будут кнопки "Сеть" "CSS" "JS" "Защита" "Журнал". Включите журнал и все заработает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Что значит "не работает"? Где не работает? Проверьте подключенные на странице скрипты: переменную console можно переопределить, изменив таким образом стандартное поведение. Это можно сделать нечайно (например, в случае ошибки `=` вместо `==` или `===`).

Comment: не работает на любом сайте

Comment: Смотрите в набор плагинов. Отрубите все для начала

Comment: Отключил весь js на странице и нечего

Answer (score 1):

Что есть сам объект console у Вас? Должен быть такой: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проверьте, не переопределил ли его какой-либо скрипт.